# Альтернатива innerHTML

Tags: php, javascript, jquery

Есть альтернатива innerHTML?
Есть код приходящий с сервера:
PHP:

```
$html = '
        Тут див с фотографией
        <script src="../assets/js/app.js"></script>
        <script src="../assets/js/plugins/magnific-popup/magnific-popup.min.js"></script>

        <script>
            jQuery(function () {
            App.initHelpers(\'magnific-popup\');
            });
        </script>
';
```

Мы его получаем и нужно его вывести на экран

```
document.getElementById('content').innerHTML = data.html;
```

Но тут проблема `Если в innerHTML есть тег script – он не будет выполнен.`
Если его вывести через append, то все работает, но текст добавляется к уже имеющемуся тексту, а нужна замена, как это делает innerHTML

Comment: а нельзя очистить контент а потом `append` сделать?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Раз уж у тебя есть jQuery, то его и используй. Оно выполняет скрипты при вставке через `$smth.html(someHtml)`.

Answer (score 1):

Как насчет создания нового дочернего объекта?

```
function createLabel(val) {
   var a = document.createElement("a");
      a.innerHTML = val;
         document.getElementById(id_of_element).appendChild(a);
}
```

Здесь также через `appendChild`, но другого выхода нет (кроме `document.write`, но он стирает все остальное. Можно заранее  ставить пробелы (" текст с пробелом спереди") или юзать `/n`

Answer (score 0):

```
document.getElementById('content').innerHTML = "";
// потом append
```